# MudBlazor Dialog is not showing on page load

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I have a blazor webassembly project with a page that loads data in a table after the user has navigated to the page. When the data is getting retrieved, I want to show a dialog which is informing the user that the retrieve data process is currently in progress and hide the dialog when the data loading is finished.

The dialog is working, I can confirm this with a button that is calling the same code. But when the user is navigating to the page, the dialog isn't showing. And I cannot figure out why.

I have managed to reproduce my issue in a new scaffold project. This is a Blazor WebAssembly App with ASP.NET Core hosted checked while creating the project. After creating the project, I [manually installed](https://mudblazor.com/getting-started/installation#manual-install-add-script-reference) MudBlazor into my project. Then I made the following changes:

- I added a file LoadingDialog.razor to the Client\Shared folder with the code:

```
<MudDialog>
    <DialogContent>
        Loading...
    </DialogContent>
</MudDialog>
```

- I changed the C# code in the Client\Pages\FetchData.razor from

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("WeatherForecast");
}
```

to

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() => await Refresh();

public async Task Refresh()
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(DialogService);

    var options = new DialogOptions
    {
        CloseOnEscapeKey = false
    };

    var dialog = DialogService.Show<LoadingDialog>("Loading", options);
    StateHasChanged();

    try
    {
        forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("WeatherForecast");        
    }
    finally
    {
        dialog.Close();
    }
}
```

The `StateHasChanged()` calling is an attempt to make the dialog appear on pageload but without success. It seems to do nothing, at least, not something visible at least.

- I also added a button to the Client\Pages\FetchData.razor above the `<table>` tag:

`<button @onclick="Refresh">Refresh</button>`

This button I use to test the dialog and when I click the button, the dialog does appear and goes away, it works like it should be.

- I also added a `task.delay(2000)` to the Server\WeatherForecastController.cs in the `Get()` to prevent the dialog from flashing away almost instantly.

Is it technically possible to show the dialog on a page load? if it is, what do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Using a dialog to show the user that the data is loading is note optimal. try MudOverlay with MudProgress inside. it's easier and don't have to charge another page

Comment: @LYass thank you for the tip. I tried it and it does indeed what I want.

Comment: @LYass Is there an example of that somewhere?

Comment: @Ionix it's pretty simple, try to look at : https://mudblazor.com/components/overlay#z-index . Replace the "Hide Overlay" button with MudProgress component.